# onClick not firing when using fontawesome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, font-awesome

I have a react component SearchField which is a wrapper around input. Im trying to get a fontawesome (x) to clear the input box when clicked, but all attempts to get the onClick to fire have failed.

If I cut and paste to the parent div, the onClick fires.
If i change the  element to a  element it still fails.
Ive tried manually positioning it outside of the input using chrome tools, and it still fails to fire.
Ive tried increasing the width and height, which also fails.

Note: _base is a wrapper around React.Component

Here's the code:

```
import React, { PropTypes }    from 'react';
import _Base                   from '_Base';
import _                       from 'underscore';
import classNames              from 'classnames';

export default class SearchField extends _Base {
  static defaultProps = {
    name:          null,
    placeholder:   null,
    onSearch:      null,
    searchOnEnter: true,
    liveSearch:    false,
    delay:         250
  };

  static propTypes = {
    name:          PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    placeholder:   PropTypes.string,
    onSearch:      PropTypes.func,
    searchOnEnter: PropTypes.bool,
    liveSearch:    PropTypes.bool,
    delay:         PropTypes.number,
  };

  state = {
    __value: null
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let me = this;
    if(props.delay > 0){
      me.onKeyDown = _.debounce(me._onKeyDown, props.delay);
    } else {
      me.onKeyDown = me._onKeyDown;
    }
  }

  __onKeyDown(event) {
    event.persist();
    this.onKeyDown(event);
  }

  _onKeyDown(e) {
    var me = this
      , props = me.props
      , val   = me.refs.search.value
      ;

    me.setState({ __value: val });

    if(props.liveSearch ||
      (props.searchOnEnter && e.key === "Enter")) {
      me._onSearch(val);
      return;
    }
  }

  _clearSearch() {
    var me = this;

    me.refs.search.value = "";
    me.setState({ __value: "" });

    me._onSearch("");
  }

  _onSearch(val) {
    var me = this
      , props = me.props
      ;

    if(props.onSearch) {
      props.onSearch({ name: props.name, value: val });
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className={classNames("search-field form-group has-feedback", this.props.className)}>
        <input
          ref            = {"search"}
          className      = "form-control"
          type           = "search"
          autoCapitalize = "none"
          autoComplete   = "off"
          autoCorrect    = "on"
          autoSave       = "true"
          autofocus      = "false"
          spellCheck     = "false"
          name           = {this.props.name}
          placeholder    = {this.props.placeholder}
          onKeyDown      = {this.__onKeyDown}
        />
        <i className="fa fa-times-circle cursor-pointer form-control-feedback"
           onClick = {this._clearSearch}
           title   = "Clear Search"
        />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you reproduce this in a jsfiddle or something? Here's a base you can fork (where the onClick fires when the icon is clicked): https://jsfiddle.net/saeq0nz0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same code works fine for me, make sure you don't have any elements overlaid on top, and that theres no css disabling the mouse events like a `pointer-events: none`

Comment: It was exactly the css pointer-events:none that was stopping it, thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

The reason this is happening is because the correct  `this` is not available inside your _clearSearch function. You need to bind it explicitely .

In your constructor function, do

```
this._clearSearch = this._clearSearch.bind(this);
```

it should work. Let us know if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: I don't think that's it. The context never changes here, so `this` should refer to the SearchField component.

Comment: In ES6 React.Component doesn't auto bind methods to itself. You need to bind them explicetly in constructor. In your jsfiddle console.log(this) you would know. https://jsfiddle.net/saeq0nz0/1/